# MySql: order lists by number of items and then by content

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I use MySql 5.7 and I need to sort lists which are stored like this:

```
| list_id | item   | item_index |
| ------- | ------ | ---------- |
| 0       | apple  | 0          |
| 0       | bread  | 1          |
| 1       | apple  | 0          |
| 1       | banana | 1          |
| 2       | orange | 0          |
```

But these items **aren't necessarily strings**, they can be integer or boolean, it's just a simplification.

Lists should be ordered by:

1. number of items in list
2. if two lists have the same number of items, then their items should be compared in order of item_index

So the result for this example should be:

1. 2 - orange
2. 1 - apple, banana
3. 0 - apple, bread

I use `group by` and `count(*)` to sort by list length, but the problem is - how to sort by list content if maximum number of items in list is unknown?

The only solution that I've came up with is to do `N` left joins on the same table, where `N` is this unknown maximum list length, each join for every possible list item. See table and my attempt to sort it on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Qo7TpSbEJk5BVZiGtH42L/0).

Are there any ways to sort it this way without knowing the maximum amount of items in list?

Comment: By "length" of list do you mean "ascending order of count of items in the list"

Comment: I can't figure out what the question is trying to accomplish, or what "length" is as there is no measure of length or field called length in the table. - Ah I get it now. All items of given list_id are the same list. You want largest list first (and so on), then within each list the items of each list in order (by index).

Comment: yes, it's number of items, "ascending order of count of items in the list", I'll edit it

Comment: by "if number of items is the same, items should be compared in the order of their item_index - 0 with 0, etc" do you mean "if two lists have the same number of items, then listitems should be compared in order of itemindex and alphabetical ordering be used to decide which list comes first)"

Comment: I'm also not really clear on whether you want row-by-row out of this (desire a result with 5 rows?) or do you want a grouped/aggregated set (unique list id, column of N list items in one, output 3 rows)

Comment: I want to compare each item of the first list with the corresponding item of the second list. e.g the first list has (1, 3, 3) and the second has (1, 2, 3) - the second list comes first, because 2 < 3. The result set should contain ids of lists.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Like this, if you want 5 rows out of your fiddle:

```
select * from 

  --the main data
  grocery_lists gl

  --joined with
  inner join

  --the count of items in each list
  (
    select list_id, group_concat(item order by item_index asc) as grouped_items, count(*) as total_count 
    from grocery_lists gl
    group by list_id
  ) ct
  on gl.list_id = ct.list_id

--ordered by the count of items, then the index 
order by ct.total_count, ct.grouped_items, gl.item_index
```

You thus get rows out like:

```
   2, orange, 0  --sorts first because count - 1
   1, apple, 0   --sorts ahead of list 0 because "apple, banana" < "apple, bread"
   1, banana, 1
   0, apple, 0
   0, bread, 1
```

#### If list items are ints (and you want 5 rows)

I think you'll need to do this:

```
select * from 

  --the main data
  grocery_lists gl

  --joined with
  inner join

  --the count of items in each list
  (
    select list_id, group_concat(LPAD(item, 10, '0') order by item_index asc) as grouped_items, count(*) as total_count 
    from grocery_lists gl
    group by list_id
  ) ct
  on gl.list_id = ct.list_id

--ordered by the count of items, then by padded aggregate ints, then index 
order by ct.total_count, ct.grouped_items, gl.item_index
```

If your items are ints, padding them out to eg 10 wide with 0 makes the sort work because "0000000123, 00000000124" < "0000000123, 0000000125"

I picked 10 wide because int max is 4.5 billion; 10 digits. if your ints will be smaller, you can pad less

If youre comparing booleans, a similar strategy, maybe convert them to INTs (true=0, false=1 ?) so they sort ocrrectly, even when aggregated into a string..

If a list of T,T,F sorts ahead of T,F,F, then make T=0 and F=1.. for example

#### If you want 3 rows out of your fiddle..

Borrowed from Shadow, and adjusted for `item` being an int:

```
select list_id, group_concat(item order by item_index asc) as items, count(*) as list_length
from yourtable
group by list_id
order by list_length asc, group_concat(LPAD(item, 8, '0') order by item_index asc) asc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can order by `count(*)` and then by `group_concat(item)` to sort by the length of the list and then by comparing the items:

```
select list_id, group_concat(item order by item_index asc) as items, count(*) as list_length
from yourtable
group by list_id
order by list_length asc, items asc
```

Update:

If you want to order numbers, then group_concat() still works because mysql implicitly converts numbers to strings. Just left pad the numbers with 0s to ensure correct sorting because with string comparison 19 is less than 2. So, change the group_concat in the order by as follows (an integer can't have more than 10 digits):

```
group_concat(LPAD(item, 10, '0') order by item_index asc)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've missed an important point - these items aren't necessarily strings, they may also be integer. I can't aggregate them, they should be compared with each other

Comment: @NadezhdaRatskevich Mysql is not a spreadsheet tool, you can't have different data types in a column.

Comment: Surely they all have the same type, but I need the solution which would also work on another table which has integer/boolean items, like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVEhJ29gP1CRgRbG5Q9WzP/1

Comment: I think this is as close as you'll reasonably get in mysql. If the data is not string, convert it and pad it so it is and sorts correctly - see the edit i made to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I'm not sure about the order

```
SELECT list_id,GROUP_CONCAT(item SEPARATOR ' ') aggregate_items ,SUM(item_index) aggregate_item_index 
FROM grocery_list
GROUP BY list_id
ORDER BY list_id DESC,COUNT(item) ASC,SUM(item_index) ASC
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that it should also work if items are integer or boolean, like in this table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aVEhJ29gP1CRgRbG5Q9WzP/1

Comment: It works. GROUP_CONCAT work with integer and boolean values.

Comment: Yeah, it does not fail, but 2 will be considered more than 19 because of string comparison.

Comment: The column in order is count, not group_concat

Comment: It's ok now? It is not necessary that the column in the group by clause to be in the displayed columns.